# How to make alerts in Angular with EventEmitter?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating Angular application and I want to make alert. I am going to use them in the situations when I send POST/PUT/DELETE request and I want some success-message to be displayed. I did it once with creating a class:

```
export class alert{
    "status" : boolean;
    "text": string;
    constructor(){
        this.status=false;
        this.text="";
    }
    public setAlert(text){
        this.status = true;
        this.text = text;
    }
    public close(){
        this.status = false;
    }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div *ngIf = "alert.status"  class="alert alert-success 
            alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"
              (click) = "alert.close()">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
              {{alert.text}}
            </div>
```

and component.ts:

```
import { alert } from './alert';

  alert: alert;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.alert = new alert();

  }

  editForm() {

    fetch(this.formService.formsUrl + "/" + this.formService.form.id, {

      method: 'PUT',

      body: JSON.stringify(this.formService.form),

      headers: {

        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"

      }

    })

    .then(response => response.json())

    .then(json => console.log(json));

    this.alert.setAlert("Post has been successfully saved !");

  }
```

I was told that the better way is to do it with EventEmmiter. So could you please give me some advice on how to do it?

Answer (score -1):

Usually you don't develop it on your own but use libraries to display messages. Commonly used is the [snackbar](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview) from Angular Material.

Answer (score -1):

Building on Julien's answer which is a very good already built-in suggestion, I suggest you create a `service` and implement different kinds of notifications you need and call the service to show your notification for you, this way in case of any changes you will need to just modify your service.

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarRef } from '@angular/material';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotificationService {

  constructor(public snack: MatSnackBar) { }
  showNotification(message: string, action: any, duration: number): MatSnackBarRef<any> {
    return this.snack.open(message, action, { duration: duration , verticalPosition: 'top', horizontalPosition: 'right'});
  }
}
```

Then you just need to inject the service in your components and use the `showNotification` function which of course you can change based on your needs.